# What does "pause" mean in Covid19 Vaccine Clinical Trials?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, clinical-study

Johnson and Johnson as well as Astra Zeneca recently announced that they were going to "pause" in their respective clinical trials for a Covid19 vaccine.

What exactly are they "pausing"?
I would expect that participants who have received the innoculation(s) would continue to be followed per the protocol schedule. So no "pause" there, right ?

The only things I can think of that they might be pausing is recruitment, and those participants who have qualified but not been given their innoculation(s) yet.

Something I'm missing?